# What does the dot and plus operator mean?

Tags: haskell

I tried googling it but I couldn't find a simple explanation. Can someone explain how this function works?

```
import Data.Char

encode :: Int -> String -> String
encode offset msg = map (chr . (+ offset) . ord) msg
```

I understand that it's mapping the `(chr . (+ offset) . ord)` function to `msg`, but what is happening inside `(chr . (+ offset) . ord)`.

Comment: `f . g . h = f . (g . h) = \x -> f (g (h x))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing to notice is there are 3 functions composed together, and will be composed in this order:

```
1. ord
2. (+ offset)
3. chr
```

The first converts a character to a number. The second will add an offset to a number. The third will convert a number back to a character. Chained together they act as follow in an imperative style:

```
function encodeChar(int ord)
{
    x = ord
    y = x + offset
    z = chr y
    return z
}
```

The `(+ offset)` notiation gives a function because `+` takes two arguments and one is being applied. The other is yet to be applied. So you get an `Int -> Int` function.

The three functions composed give a function that takes a `Char` and returns a `Char` and can therefore be mapped to a list of `Char`s, i.e. a `String`.